# Configure CIFilter to match the effect of SKWarpGeometry

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cifilter

I am using the [warpGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skwarpable/1690953-warpgeometry) feature of Sprite Kit extensively to display deformed images.

I would also like to use this distortion effect off screen, without instantiating a SKScene and so on, by configuring a corresponding CIFilter. However, I cannot find the corresponding filter among [all available ones](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW118).

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent CIFilter is `CIPerspectiveTransform`. Alternatively, you could also consider using `CIAffineTransform`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I agree that I could manually determine an CGAffineTransform for each rectangle of the input regular grid that realises the corresponding deformation. Depending on the grid size, however, this is not really effective, and instead of handling one image, I would have to process each rectangular sub-image one-after-the-other.

Comment: I think if it's a once-off transform then the CIFilter will work well. But if you want to animate the image being transformed (like you can animate warps in spritekit), then I guess you would need to create a whole lot of images using the CIFilter, and then animate by replacing the image with the next image in the list every X milliseconds. This could work, but I'm not sure if it won't be too heavy in terms of processing to prepare all those images in real time. Somehow spritekit manages to do the warps without being too heavy on the processing...

Comment: Don't know if this will be directly applicable to your needs, but maybe have a look at this tutorial where they animate the menu almost like one would animate with warps in spritekit: https://www.raywenderlich.com/87268/3d-effect-taasky-swift. They don't use CIFilters, but use other things to animate and give a feeling of a 3D perspective.